# is there something equaivlent getChildViewByID in android

Tags: android, view

I want to get a a `childView` whose name is "name" inside a `ViewGroup`. I knew that the `nameView` is the second item inside the GroupView, so I used following code:

```
TextView nameView =  (TextView)((ViewGroup)view).getChildAt(2); //2 is magic number
```

However, it is possible that ,in the future,  I might add some other Views before the `nameView` and above code will became invalid.  So, I am wondering how could get the ChildView by name, something like:

```
     TextView nameView =  (TextView)((ViewGroup)view).getChildByID(R.id.name);
```

EDIT: thanks to kcoppock. I realize `getChildByName("name")` does not make sense. So i will purse something like `getChildByID`.

Comment: What do you mean its name is "name"? Its ID? This doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You method are looking for is View.findViewById(id). Per your example:

```
TextView nameView =  (TextView) view.findViewByID(R.id.name);
```

(It is not necessary to cast to ViewGroup)

Barry

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to find a particular child of a ViewGroup by its ID, just first get a reference to the ViewGroup:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.myGroupLayout);
```

Then call `findViewById()` on that ViewGroup:

```
View v = (TextView)vg.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Comment: +1 for letting me knowing i could get a viewGroup by id as well!